# I cannot get value from the checkbox in order to generate SQL statement from the code below

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot get value from the checkbox in order to generate SQL statement from the code below
 I have been trying to look for the flaw in my code, but I have no idea at all.

```
<?
session_start();

if( isset($_POST['swimming'])&&
    isset($_POST['driving'])&&
    isset($_POST['cooking'])&&
    isset($_POST['cycling'])&&
    isset($_POST['bacom'])&&
    isset($_POST['baacc']))
{

$sql = "SELECT position_id FROM `jobskill_info`
    where skill_id in (1";

if (document.match.swimming.checked) {
    $sql .= ",10";
}elseif (document.match.driving.checked) {
    $sql .= ",11";
}elseif (document.match.cooking.checked) {
    $sql .= ",12";
}elseif (document.match.cycling.checked) {
    $sql .= ",13";
}elseif (document.match.bacom.checked) {
    $sql .= ",14";
}elseif (document.match.baacc.checked) {
    $sql .= ",15";
}

$count = 0;

if (document.match.swimming.checked) {
    $count = $count+1;
}elseif (document.match.driving.checked) {
    $count = $count+1;
}elseif (document.match.cooking.checked) {
    $count = $count+1;
}elseif (document.match.cycling.checked) {
    $count = $count+1;
}elseif (document.match.bacom.checked) {
    $count = $count+1;
}elseif (document.match.baacc.checked) {
    $count = $count+1;
}

$sql .= ") group by position_id having count(*) = ".$count."";

echo "$sql";
}

?>
```

HTML PART
here is the HTML part where I want to get the value from the checkbox.

```
<html>
<title>Matching Skill Systems</title>
<form name=match method=post action=test2.php onSubmit="return checkData()">
<table width=100% border=1 cellpadding="20">
    <tr bgcolor=red>
        <td colspan=3><font size=10 color=orange><center></center></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height= 300px>
        <td width=200px></td>
        <td><center><h1>Matching Skills</h1><br>
                <table border=3>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=5><center>Personal Skill</center></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type=checkbox name=swimming value="10" id=swimming >Swimming</td>
                    <td><input type=checkbox name=driving value="11" id=driving >Driving</td>
                    <td><input type=checkbox name=cooking value="12" id=cooking >Cooking</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name=cycling value="13" id=cycling>Cycling</td>
                    <td><input type=checkbox name=bacom value="14" id=bacom>Basic computer</td>
                    <td><input type=checkbox name=baacc value="15" id=baacc>Basic accounting</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </table><br>
                <input type=submit name=match value=Matching>
                <input type=button value=Back onclick="location.href='applicantprofile.php'"><br>
                <br>
                <table border=5>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=400px><center><h4>Job Decription</h4></center></td>
                        <td width=150px><center><h4>Available Position</h4></center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </td>
        <td width=200px></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: you are mixing php and javascript.. `if (document.match.swimming.checked) $sql .= ",10";` - the if statement is javascript and the concatenation is php

Comment: BTW, `isset` accepts multiple arguments: `isset($_POST['swimming'], $_POST['driving'], $_POST['cooking'], ...)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a big mistake in your code.
You combined JavaScript and PHP in a wrong way. You can not do this:

```
if (document.match.swimming.checked) {
    $sql .= ",10";
}elseif (document.match.driving.checked) {
    $sql .= ",11";
}elseif (document.match.cooking.checked) {
    $sql .= ",12";
}elseif (document.match.cycling.checked) {
    $sql .= ",13";
}elseif (document.match.bacom.checked) {
    $sql .= ",14";
}elseif (document.match.baacc.checked) {
    $sql .= ",15";
}
```

You have JavaScript IF statement, and for each block you have a PHP action. This is wrong.
For what you want, you should do something like this :

```
<?php
session_start();

if( isset($_POST['swimming'])&&
    isset($_POST['driving'])&&
    isset($_POST['cooking'])&&
    isset($_POST['cycling'])&&
    isset($_POST['bacom'])&&
    isset($_POST['baacc']))
{
   $sql = "SELECT position_id FROM `jobskill_info` where skill_id in (1";

   if ($_POST['swimming'] == '1') {
       $sql .= ",10";
   } elseif ($_POST['driving'] == '1') {
       $sql .= ",11";
   } // Next lines in this way ...


   $sql .= ") group by position_id having count(*) = ".$count."";

   echo "$sql";

}
?>
```

Also you must follow this way in your HTML codes for each checkbox:

```
<input type=checkbox name="swimming" value="1" id="swimming" />Swimming
```

By the way, always use `<?php` instead of `<?` in your applications. I will guarantee your project to be worked without any problem everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is this one:

```
if( isset($_POST['swimming'])&&
    isset($_POST['driving'])&&
    isset($_POST['cooking'])&&
    isset($_POST['cycling'])&&
    isset($_POST['bacom'])&&
    isset($_POST['baacc']))
```

An HTML checkbox only posts *any* value if it is checked. Remove the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You are, as people have already pointed out, mixing Javascript and PHP. Since you don't report the many errors messages this code would give you in the question, I'm guessing you have error reporting disabled - you should turn it up to max while developing, and only turn it off in production. You can easily do this by placing the following lines at the top of you PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now, on to the code:

Firstly, you will need to remove that `isset()` tree at the top of the script. A checkbox will only be present in the POST data if it was checked - checking if they are all set before you execute and code means that your code will only be executed when *all* the checkboxes are checked, which I imagine is not what you want.

Nextly, you should avoid hard-coding database ID's into your code. You can use those values that were passed back to your code from the page, as long as you sanitise them before using them in your SQL. Since they are all integers, you just need to cast them to integers.

Nextly, let's abstract the `$_POST` array from the SQL. First we'll look at the values in `$_POST` and build an array of data you use in the SQL, *then* we'll build the SQL. This will massively improve readability and maintainability.

Try this PHP code:

```
<?php

  // Always use a full <?php tag, the shortened <? is not widely supported

  session_start();

  // An array of all the skill_id values we will search for
  $skillIds = array(1);

  // An array of all the checkbox names
  $skillChecks = array (
    'swimming',
    'driving',
    'cooking',
    'cycling',
    'bacom',
    'baacc'
  );

  // Loop the checks and get the values from $_POST
  foreach ($skillChecks as $skill) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$skill])) {
      $skillIds[] = (int) $_POST[$skill]; // Cast them to ints so they are SQL-safe
    }
  }

  // Get the value for $count
  $count = count($skillIds) - 1;

  // Build the query
  $sql = "
    SELECT `position_id`
    FROM `jobskill_info`
    WHERE `skill_id` IN (".implode(", ", $skillIds).")
    GROUP BY `position_id`
    HAVING count(*) = $count
  ";

  echo "$sql";
```

Please also note that **all** attribute values in HTML should be quoted. So:

```
<td><input type=checkbox name=swimming value="10" id=swimming >Swimming</td>
```

...should be:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="swimming" value="10" id="swimming">Swimming</td>
```

You should also add a doctype to the top of the HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```